# Quartz 2D -Drawing a point

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, quartz-2d

I know that drawing a point by using drawing a line method in Quartz 2D is

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,x,y-0.5f);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,x,y+0.5f);
```

Is there any other possible way to draw a point using Quartz?
I meant, some direct way of doing so?

Comment: What do you mean by "point"? A pixel? A rectangle of one by one point dimension? The presented code draws a diagonal line, not a point.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe oops added wrong code.Sorry,edited.I am mentioning about a pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x,y,1,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to look like a circular point try this:

```
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(x, y, 4, 4));
```

it will draw for you you a an ellipse inside a rectangle (above case is apparently a square). i prefer you to choose a square as it will look like a real circle and not oval one. however, this circle will be empty from the inside, you can fill it by a stroke. (but it looks cool like a donut!) :)